# Checking If the Browser Has Finished Loading the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I spent mad time the in the last couple of days trying to find some code that allows me to do something when the browser has finished loading the page.

I found this code at http://callmenick.com/post/check-if-everything-loaded-with-javascript

```
<script>
var everythingLoaded = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
      clearInterval(everythingLoaded);
      $('div#loader').hide();
      $('div#main-container').fadeIn(1200);
    }
}, 10);
</script>
```

This piece of code does work, but for some reason that I can't understand it **interferes with** this function when the page is first loaded. But once I do any **resize**, the function fires

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    equalTiles(); //sets the height equal to calculated width

    $(window).on('load resize orientationchange',function(){ 
        equalTiles();
    });

});
```

Comment: Working here! https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/g0tkkxbk/

Comment: Hi. I'm not quite sure I understand the problem. Are you saying that you can't use both code blocks together? Why do you need the first one - which seems to be a test for document loaded without jQuery if you have jQuery?

Comment: because when I use jQuery window load function, the required functions fire before all images and stuff are fully loaded :S

Comment: `$(window).on('load')` will fire when all resources are loaded (images included), so I can't understand why in your case it doesn't

Comment: I have already tried $(window).on('load') first thing before my research starts. It does fire the functions before images are completely loaded in

Comment: the onload triggers before the page has finished loading

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `$(document).ready()` helper is different to the window load event. Here is the difference:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // The browser is now aware of the entire DOM structure,
  // but images and other resources may not have finished downloading yet.
  // Include code here that depends on a DOM element being present,
  // but doesn't depend on images being fully loaded yet.

  // It looks none of your code actually wants to be in here as it all depends on images.
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
  // All images are loaded now.
  // Include code here that depends on images being loaded.

  equalTiles();
  $('div#loader').hide();
  $('div#main-container').fadeIn(1200);

  $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function(){ 
    equalTiles();
  });
});
```

Comment: Josh, thank you for your answer. I know that, but for some reason the $(window).on("load", function() does fire my desired code before images are fully loaded !

Comment: Is it not just because you are calling `equalTiles()` as the first line in `$(document).ready(...)`? You should remove that call to `equalTiles` and only call it inside the window load handler. That is what I was trying to explain at a more abstract level.

Comment: same problem they only fires when I do a resize, not on load

Comment: And I would remove the entire `var everythingLoaded` snippet as you can use `$(document).ready()` in place of that.

Comment: the onload triggers before the page has finished loading

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Josh's answer, and more commonly, pass in a function to the `jQuery` or `$` directly.

```
$(function() {
    // code that runs once the window is ready
});
```

Comment: the onload triggers before the page has finished loading